# Why do so many people insist on using incomprehensible, obscure, ambiguous acronyms all the time?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, comprehension

> I work in clinical healthcare. I won't be able to step away any time I
>   want and we are already having problems getting PPE.

Okay? "PPE"? Then I have to manually look that up on Wikipedia, and get this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPE

And that's not even one of the worst ones. They can often be *full* of things it could refer to, in a huge list, impossible to know from the context. My above example is just what I read just now which prompted me to ask this.

Do they think it makes them sound smarter to use an acronym that only they know what it means? Do they like wasting the readers' time? I don't get it. Unless the context is crystal-clear, and it's been used before in the same text, it seems idiotic to use these random acronyms that just slow down and confuse the readers.

Comment: Thank heavens the meaning of "POS" is well-established and not ambiguous.  Otherwise all the questions here like "What POS is this?" would be misinterpreted.

Comment: "Why" questions like this one risk closure because they seem more like like peeves than legitimate requests for information.  They are also unanswerable absent serious research into the particulars,  which is unlikely to have been performed.

Comment: Absent particular context, I doubt someone is maliciously using abbreviations to force you to look them up. It's more likely that they fell back on frequent usage, or forgot their audience. I can't write a valid answer about something so broad, but if you wanted to rewrite the question to be about  something more specific (e.g. how common is the use of PPE versus personal protective equipment), that could be useful!

Comment: This is really more of a rant than a genuine inquiry. Reddit is a more appropriate forum.

Comment: The problem isn't acronyms specifically, it's that jargon terms - many of which are not acronyms - may not be well known by outsiders. In the case of "PPE", however, I think almost all people who have a job (any job) *should* be familiar with the term because all jobs should involve at least minimal occupational health and safety (OHS) training - employers that don't provide such training are taking a risk - and even abbreviated OHS courses usually mention PPE.

Comment: Perhaps Ponder Editing

Answer (score 2):

Why did you write "ambiguous" instead of "with several possible meanings and no way to know which one is meant"? You didn't write it in order to feel smart or because you wanted to waste my time, did you? You wrote it because that's the word that came to mind and you thought people would understand it.

The same goes for acronyms. The term "PPE" is pretty common (in some groups, at least); it comes to mind naturally and most people in the intended audience are going to understand it right away. So of course people are going to use that term.

It's not hard to find out what "PPE" means using, say, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=PPE&oldid=54609820) (3 definitions, and the first one is the intended meaning here) or [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+ppe) (9 results on the first page for me, and *all* of them are the intended meaning here).

(If you're in the habit of using Wikipedia to try to find out what words and acronyms mean, stop doing that and use a dictionary instead. If you're trying to figure out what the word "amazing" means and you look it up on Wikipedia, [you'll be disappointed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Amazing&oldid=894902589).)

Answer (score 1):

People use jargon to establish themselves as members of their “in-group”.  It’s annoying in many ways, sometimes even to members of the in-group itself.

This article by Joel Klettke gives a slightly different perspective on its use, and the accompanying video is quite funny.

https://businesscasualcopywriting.com/why-people-who-hate-jargon-are-wrong/

Joel points out that sometimes the purpose of jargon is to filter out readers for whom the text has no relevance.